# Spring Framework JMS Destination name resolution approach

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I wanted to encapsulate the details of creating / resolving a destination into some sort of DestinationResolver implementation.

The details being creating a connection, creating a session, creating / resolving a destination.

Would such an implementation be a bad approach?

```
public class SessionAwareDestinationResolver extends DynamicDestinationResolver {

    private Session session;

    @Inject
    public SessionAwareDestinationResolver(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        try {
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            throw JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Destination resolveDestinationName(String destinationName,
            boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
        return super.resolveDestinationName(session, destinationName,
                pubSubDomain);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Would a better approach just to wrap the specific task in an execute action?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#execute(org.springframework.jms.core.SessionCallback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understood you, [JmsTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) already provides a very good abstraction to sending/receiving message from JMS providers - you do not have to deal with raw JMS ConnectionFactory or Session. Unless you have a specific need for a Session - say to implement a queue browser or a request/response in the same session etc, if that is the case the approach of using a SessionCallback with execute method of JmsTemplate like you have mentioned is a good idea rather than needing to write your own abstraction.

Comment: I needed a way to resolve destinatons without needing a session. Using the template provides me with the means